# Rustのhtml5everのremove_from_parent関数の使用方法を教えてください

Tags: rust

Rustのhtml5everを使用して、HTMLをパースし、一部を削除した結果を出力したいです。
調べたところ、`remove_from_parent` という関数を使用出来るかと考えています。

https://docs.rs/markup5ever/0.10.0/markup5ever/interface/tree_builder/trait.TreeSink.html#tymethod.remove_from_parent

例として、`remove_from_parent` 関数を使い、span要素を全て削除するサンプルを作ろうとしています。
現在のコードの一部は以下です。
`// remove all span element here` のコメントの箇所で削除しようとしています。
どのように削除すれば良いでしょうか？

lin.rs

```
extern crate html5ever;
extern crate markup5ever;
extern crate markup5ever_rcdom;

use markup5ever_rcdom::{NodeData, RcDom, Handle, SerializableHandle};
use html5ever::parse_document;
use html5ever::serialize::{SerializeOpts, serialize};
use html5ever::tendril::TendrilSink;

use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use web_sys::console::log_1;

#[wasm_bindgen]
extern {
    pub fn alert(s: &str);
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn convert() {
    let data = "<html><body><span>should be removed</span></body></html>";
    let dom: RcDom = parse_document(RcDom::default(), Default::default()).one(data);

    search_iter(&dom.document, &dom);

    let mut bytes = vec![];
    let document: SerializableHandle = dom.document.clone().into();
    serialize(&mut bytes, &document, SerializeOpts::default()).unwrap();
    let converted_html = String::from_utf8(bytes).unwrap();

    alert(&format!("{:?}", converted_html));
}

fn search_iter(node: &Handle, dom: &RcDom) {
    match node.data {
        NodeData::Element { ref name, .. } => {
            if name.local.to_string().eq("span") {
                log_1(&JsValue::from("This is span tag"));
                // remove all span element here
            }
        },
        _ => {}
    };
    for child in node.children.borrow().iter() {
      search_iter(child, dom);
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2"
html5ever = "0.25.1"
markup5ever = "0.10.0"
markup5ever_rcdom = "0.1.0"
web-sys = {"version" = "0.3.44", features=['console']}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
        import * as mod  from "./hello_wasm.js";
        (async () => {
            await mod.default();
            mod.convert();
        })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 「使用方法について」で止まっていて、結局何に困っているのかが説明されていないように見受けられます。

Comment: 「spanタグを全て要素する」の意味がわかりません。「削除する」でしょうか？

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。文章を修正しました。remove_from_parentを使ってどのように要素を削除すれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: 文章を修正していただき、ありがとうございました。回答を記入しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 調べたところ、remove_from_parent という関数を使用出来るかと考えています

私はhtml5everを使ったことがないので少し手こずりましたが、ご質問の答えはわかりました。以下のようにして調べました。

1. 質問で挙げられていたmarkup5everクレートのドキュメントを読んだ

   - `remove_from_parent`は`TreeSink`トレイトのメソッドであることがわかった
   - しかし、markup5everにはその`TreeSink`トレイトを実装している型がない
2. markup5everとhtml5everのGitHubリポジトリーで、examplesフォルダー内にあるサンプルを見てみた

   - 手がかりになりそうな情報はなかった
3. GitHubでコード検索した。（検索ワード：`remove_from_parent`、言語：Rust）

   - 検索結果：https://github.com/search?l=Rust&q=remove_from_parent&type=Code
   - 参考になりそうなコードが見つかった：[brave/brave-core - scorer.rs#L192-L198](https://github.com/brave/brave-core/blob/612896e4b30cca7352dfe2aa1247e2995f97b580/components/speedreader/rust/lib/src/readability/src/scorer.rs#L192-L198)

検索で見つかったコードから、`TreeSink`トレイトはご質問のコードで使われている`RcDom`が実装していることがわかりました。（`RcDom`はmarkup5ever_rcdomクレートにある）

つまり、以下のように書けそうです。

```rust
            if name.local.to_string().eq("span") {
                log_1(&JsValue::from("This is span tag"));
                // remove all span element here
                dom.remove_from_parent(&node);   // ← この行を追加した
            }
```

しかしこれはコンパイルエラーになりました。

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*dom` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/bin/main1.rs:33:13
   |
29 | fn search_iter(node: &Handle, dom: &RcDom, nodes_to_remove: &mut Vec<Handle>) {
   |                                    ------ help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut RcDom`
...
33 |             dom.remove_from_parent(&node);
   |             ^^^ `dom` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

`remove_from_parent`は`self`として`&mut RcDom`を取ろうとするのですが、`dom`は`&RcDom`なのでできないそうです。

コンパイルエラーで勧められたとおりに何箇所か修正すると、最後はこのエラーで行き詰まりました。

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `dom` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/bin/main1.rs:14:32
   |
14 |     search_iter(&dom.document, &mut dom, &mut nodes_to_remove);
   |     ----------- -------------  ^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
   |     |           |
   |     |           immutable borrow occurs here
   |     immutable borrow later used by call
```

`dom`にはすでに不変借用があるので、可変借用を同時に作れないわけです。

参考にしたコードをもう一度見てみると、処理を2つのステップに分けていることがわかりました。

- **ステップ1**：domをトラバース（ツリー全体を移動）して、削除の対象となるノードを洗い出す。対象ノードは`Vec<RcDom>`に格納する
- **ステップ2**：洗い出したノードを削除する

これにならってコードを修正したところ、コンパイルエラーが解消し、以下のような出力が得られました。

**実行結果**

```
Found a span tag
"<html><head></head><body></body></html>"
```

修正後のコードは以下のようになります。（wasmにコンパイルしなくて済むように、`log_1()`を`println!()`で置き換えています）

```rust
use html5ever::{
    local_name, parse_document, serialize, serialize::SerializeOpts, tendril::TendrilSink,
    tree_builder::TreeSink,
};
use markup5ever_rcdom::{Handle, NodeData, RcDom, SerializableHandle};
use std::rc::Rc;

pub fn convert() {
    let data = "<html><body><span>should be removed</span></body></html>";
    let mut dom: RcDom = parse_document(RcDom::default(), Default::default()).one(data);

    // spanノードを探してnodes_to_removeに入れる
    let mut nodes_to_remove = vec![];
    search_iter(&dom.document, &dom, &mut nodes_to_remove);

    // 見つかったspanノードを削除する
    for node in nodes_to_remove {
        dom.remove_from_parent(&node);
    }

    let mut bytes = vec![];
    let document: SerializableHandle = dom.document.into();
    serialize(&mut bytes, &document, SerializeOpts::default()).unwrap();
    let converted_html = String::from_utf8(bytes).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", converted_html);
}

fn search_iter(node: &Handle, dom: &RcDom, nodes_to_remove: &mut Vec<Handle>) {
    if let NodeData::Element { ref name, .. } = node.data {
        // Local値はlocal_name!マクロで作れる
        if name.local == local_name!("span") {
            println!("Found a span tag");
            // ノードをnodes_to_removeに入れる
            nodes_to_remove.push(Rc::clone(&node));
        }
    }

    for child in node.children.borrow().iter() {
        search_iter(child, dom, nodes_to_remove);
    }
}
```

Comment: やってみたのですが、`dom.remove_from_parent(&node);`の行で、`method not found in `markup5ever_rcdom::RcDom``のエラーが出るようです。

Comment: useで`html5ever::tree_builder::TreeSink` を追加し忘れており、追加したところ動作するようになりました。非常に助かりました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 解決してよかったです！